# file is saved with zero bytes(0 bytes)

Tags: c#, asp.net

0 bytes file created when i am trying to replace the file in code behind of C#.

```
  string FileExactLocation = s + str;
  if (File.Exists(FileExactLocation))
  {
      File.Replace(FileExactLocation, FileExactLocation,"werwe");
  }   
  else
      FileUpload1.SaveAs(FileExactLocation);
```

in above code, i am trying to delete a file located on server,it gets deleted but the file which i am trying to save (replace) contains 0 bytes...its empty...

Please give me the solution to this problem....

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Why do you want to replace a file with itself?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong there is a memory leak somewhere in your code, do you want to try using 
the "using()" statement and also make sure you dispose all objects which is associated with the file

Comment: The point of using is to help you dispose objects.  It's redundant to talk about the using statement and also make sure to dispose of objects.

Comment: In the code snippet above he doesn't create any instances of the file, he just use `static` methods, so nothing to dispose of.

Comment: @Tony Correct me if I am wrong, in the above mentioned code was wrapped by a try catch finally block then the object would need to be disposed as when using 'using' statement, its not possible to use the 'finally' block.

Comment: @ho1 yes your right, but I was more thinking that there could be other code which works with this file that is not mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused about what `Replace` does. If all you want to do is to replace the original file with a new one, just delete the old one, otherwise, if you do want to keep a backup of the original file, rename it before the save.

So if my understanding is correct, I think you're looking for either:

```
  string FileExactLocation = s + str;
  if (File.Exists(FileExactLocation))
  {
      File.Delete(FileExactLocation);
  }   
  FileUpload1.SaveAs(FileExactLocation);
```

Or:

```
  string FileExactLocation = s + str;
  if (File.Exists(FileExactLocation))
  {
      // Rename the file adding werwe to the filename
      File.Move(FileExactLocation, Path.Combine(FileExactLocation, "werwe"));
  }   
  FileUpload1.SaveAs(FileExactLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason is the fileUploadcontrol value is cleared after postback...and hence u r creating .zip file with no data..
in that case u can upload file using byte streaming....